# Why is the use of the ND rule ∃E not correct in this proof?

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

[image]

Is there anyone who could explain to me why these errors occur? It seems to me the rule was used properly.

Answer (score 3):

Existential Elimination requires that the witness (`a`) does not occur in the conclusion *or* in any undischarged assumptions.

At those points, you have an undischarged assumption that includes `a` on line 2.

---

Suggestion: Place the negation introduction subproofs *inside* each case of the v-elimination subproofs.

```
|  |_ Ex -Px
|  |  |_ -Pa
|  |  |  |_ Pa & Qa
|  |  |  |  :
```

Comment: Thanks so much this helps!